# ошибка Failed to connect to server: (0)

Tags: php, phpmailer

пытаюсь послать сообщение по email,вот такая ошибка получается,использую phpMailer.

```
 require('./PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php');
 require('./PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php');
 require('./PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
 
$message = 'Never Give Up!';
$subject = 'Test mail!';
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'myhost';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'my';
$mail->Password = 'my';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
 
 
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
     $mail->From="my";
     $mail->FromName="Alex";
     $mail->addAddress('tomy');
     $mail->isHTML(true);

     $mail->Subject='Тема письма';
     $mail->Body="Привет,мир";
     $mail->AltBody="Альтернативный привет мир!";
    $mail->Send();
        if($mail->send()){
            echo 'true';
        }else{
            echo 'false';
        }
```

Comment: перевод - невозможно подключиться к серверу.

Comment: У вас что, есть мейл сервер с доступом по адресу myhost и такими учетными данными? Разберитесь сначала с основами разработки, как читать документацию и выводить страницы прежде чем лезть в сетевые дебри.